# Unable to access folders and files from amazon s3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have deployed my django code to heroku and trying to serve static and media files from amazon S3. S3 is giving access to folders created in interface but not to the folders copied by collectstatic. I have enabled s3 to act as static website and used policy below.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1380877762691",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1380877761162",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::harpoons1/*"
        }
    ]
}

Non Working link:
http://harpoons1.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/elate/
Working link:
http://harpoons1.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

Is there anyway i can give public access to every folder and file inside my S3.So can i serve them on my website. Help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is inside the folder "elate/" ?

To display a default page you will need to setup a default index document such as index.html.

This is setup in the "Static website hosting" dialog under "Properties" for the bucket.